# Connecting two interpretations of the negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, negative-binomial

In my probability course, my professor derived the negative binomial distribution by reasoning about the probability that the time of the $k$-th success, $T_k$, takes some value $n$. If $p$ is probability of success, $X_k$ is the outcome of the $k$-th Bernoulli trial and $S_n$ is the number of successes by trial $n$, then

$$
\mathbb{P}\{T_k = n\} = \mathbb{P}\{X_n = 1\} \mathbb{P}\{S_{n-1} = k-1\} = {n - 1 \choose k - 1} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}, \qquad n \geq k
$$

and he denotes this

$$
T_k \sim \text{NB}(k, p)
$$

This all makes sense.

But when I try to read about the [negative binomial distribution on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution), it was described as the probability of the number of successes until a fixed number of failures, $r$, and is denoted $X \sim \text{NB}(r, p)$.

$$
\mathbb{P}\{X = k\} = {k + r - 1 \choose k} p^k (1 - p)^r
$$

If we note that $n = k + r$, this is *almost* the same:

$$
\mathbb{P}\{X = k\} = {n - 1 \choose k} p^k (1 - p)^{n - k}
$$

Anyway, are these the same modeling assumptions? Why are they parameterized differently? Also, is there some connection between interpreting the r.v. as a time vs. a count?

Comment: I really think that the formula at wiki is not right. At the trials $1$ to $n-1$ you make $k-1$ successes. Here you have $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ way to obtain $k-1$ successes. Good catch.

Comment: It may help to read the section titled "Alternative formulations" in the Wikipedia article.